# Mapping C# 9 record as value object with EntityFrameworkCore 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, c#-9.0, ef-core-5.0

I am trying to use `record` types as value objects in a c# class, but when I try to map these types using efcore 5 it throws an exception.

My classes:

```
public record ZipCode
    {
        private static readonly char ZIPCODE_SEPARATOR = '-';
        private static readonly string INVALID_ZIPCODE_MESSAGE = "invalid zip code";
        private static readonly string ZIPCODE_WITH_NOT_ONLY_NUMBERS = "Invalid zip code value, must have only digits";

        private char[] _value;
        public string Value => new string(_value);

        public ZipCode(string zipCode)
        {
            _value = new char[8];
            setZipCodeValue(zipCode);
        }

        public ZipCode(ZipCode zipCode)
        {
            this._value = zipCode.Value.ToCharArray();
        }
        
        private void setZipCodeValue(string valueAsString)
        {
            if (valueAsString.Length < 8 || valueAsString.Length > 9)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(INVALID_ZIPCODE_MESSAGE);
            }

            var zipCodeAsCharArray = valueAsString.ToCharArray();
            int valueArrayIndex = (int) decimal.Zero;

            foreach (var ch in zipCodeAsCharArray)
            {
                if (char.IsDigit(ch) )
                {
                    _value[valueArrayIndex] = ch;
                    valueArrayIndex++;
                }
                else if (ch.Equals(ZIPCODE_SEPARATOR))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException(ZIPCODE_WITH_NOT_ONLY_NUMBERS);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Main object:

```
public class DeliveryServicePriceTime
    {
        public Guid Id { get; private set; }

        public ZipCode SourceZipCode { get; private set; }
        public ZipCode DestinationZipCode { get; private set; }

        public DateTime RequestDateTime { get; private set; }

        private IList<ServicePriceTime> _servicesPriceTime;
        public IReadOnlyList<ServicePriceTime> ServicesPriceTimes => _servicesPriceTime.ToList();
        
        private DeliveryServicePriceTime()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        }

        public DeliveryServicePriceTime(ZipCode sourceZipCode, ZipCode destinationZipCode, IList<ServicePriceTime> servicesPriceTime) : this()
        {
            SourceZipCode = sourceZipCode;
            DestinationZipCode = destinationZipCode;
            _servicesPriceTime = servicesPriceTime;
        }

        public DeliveryServicePriceTime(string sourceZipCode, string destinationZipCode, IList<ServicePriceTime> servicesPriceTime) : this()
        {
            RequestDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
            this.SourceZipCode = new ZipCode(sourceZipCode);
            this.DestinationZipCode = new ZipCode(destinationZipCode);
            _servicesPriceTime = servicesPriceTime;                
        }
    }
```

I have another `record` which the following code:

```
public record ServicePriceTime(DeliveryService DeliveryService, decimal Price, int Time);
```

I am using the fluent api to map the properties to the table structure with the following code:

```
public class DeliveryServicePriceTimeMappingConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<DeliveryServicePriceTime>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<DeliveryServicePriceTime> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("DeliveryCalcEvent");

            builder.HasKey(e => e.Id);
            builder.Property(e => e.RequestDateTime).IsRequired();

            builder.OwnsOne(e => e.SourceZipCode)
                   .Property(e => e.Value)
                   .UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.PreferFieldDuringConstruction)
                   .IsRequired();

            builder.OwnsOne(e => e.DestinationZipCode)
                   .Property(e => e.Value)
                   .UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.PreferFieldDuringConstruction)
                   .IsRequired();

            builder.OwnsMany(e => e.ServicesPriceTimes, ac =>
            {
                ac.OwnsOne(m => m.DeliveryService, pc =>
                {
                    pc.Property(p => p.ServiceCode).IsRequired();
                    pc.Property(p => p.ServiceName).IsRequired();
                }).UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.PreferFieldDuringConstruction);
                ac.Property(m => m.Price).IsRequired();
                ac.Property(m => m.Time).IsRequired();
            }).UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.PreferFieldDuringConstruction);                
        }
    }
```

I am using the method to ensure database creation on the startup class, but when I try to start the application the entity framework cannot understand my record object.

this is my stack trace:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[6]
      Application startup exception
      System.InvalidOperationException: No suitable constructor was found for entity type 'DeliveryServicePriceTime.DestinationZipCode#ZipCode'. The following constructors had parameters that could not be bound to properties of the entity type: cannot bind 'zipCode' in 'DeliveryServicePriceTime.DestinationZipCode#ZipCode(string zipCode)'; cannot bind 'zipCode' in 'DeliveryServicePriceTime.DestinationZipCode#ZipCode(ZipCode zipCode)'.
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.ConstructorBindingConvention.ProcessModelFinalizing(IConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder, IConventionContext`1 context)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ImmediateConventionScope.OnModelFinalizing(IConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.OnModelFinalizing(IConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.Model.FinalizeModel()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder.FinalizeModel()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, ModelDependencies modelDependencies)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, ModelDependencies modelDependencies)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.<>c.<TryAddCoreServices>b__7_3(IServiceProvider p)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IInfrastructure<System.IServiceProvider>.get_Instance()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DatabaseFacade.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IInfrastructure<System.IServiceProvider>.get_Instance()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.GetRelationalService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 databaseFacade)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.Migrate(DatabaseFacade databaseFacade)
         at API.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider) in /API/Startup.cs:line 52
         at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
         at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Build>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<UseStartup>b__1(IApplicationBuilder app)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.MiddlewareFilterBuilderStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>g__MiddlewareFilterBuilder|0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: No suitable constructor was found for entity type 'DeliveryServicePriceTime.DestinationZipCode#ZipCode'. The following constructors had parameters that could not be bound to properties of the entity type: cannot bind 'zipCode' in 'DeliveryServicePriceTime.DestinationZipCode#ZipCode(string zipCode)'; cannot bind 'zipCode' in 'DeliveryServicePriceTime.DestinationZipCode#ZipCode(ZipCode zipCode)'.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.ConstructorBindingConvention.ProcessModelFinalizing(IConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder, IConventionContext`1 context)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ImmediateConventionScope.OnModelFinalizing(IConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.OnModelFinalizing(IConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.Model.FinalizeModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder.FinalizeModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, ModelDependencies modelDependencies)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, ModelDependencies modelDependencies)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.<>c.<TryAddCoreServices>b__7_3(IServiceProvider p)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IInfrastructure<System.IServiceProvider>.get_Instance()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DatabaseFacade.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IInfrastructure<System.IServiceProvider>.get_Instance()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.GetRelationalService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 databaseFacade)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.Migrate(DatabaseFacade databaseFacade)
   at API.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider) in /API/Startup.cs:line 52
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Build>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<UseStartup>b__1(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.MiddlewareFilterBuilderStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>g__MiddlewareFilterBuilder|0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
```

Someone had any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Your `ZipCode` class is missing parameterless constructors, that is what the error is saying to you.

Comment: ZipCode works as a value object, so it can not have a default constructor

Comment: as for the ZipCode, why are you declaring it as `record`? records are for immutability, and that code is not.

Comment: Your constructor `ZipCode(ZipCode zipCode)` is not really needed, cause a record has already a `Clone()` method, that can be called by using `var clone = zipCode with {}`.

Comment: Also it is quite unclear from the given code, why you use a `char[]`instead of a `string`? A `string` is immutable and implements `IEnumerable<char>` for your iteration code.

Comment: I finally discovered why I am getting this exception. I don't have sure if the change that I did was the one who solves the problem, but at least I am not getting the exception anymore. I simply change the parameters on the constructors to match with the name of the property. Like: `public ZipCode(ZipCode value)` and I am not getting the exception anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, if EF Core finds a parameterized constructor with parameter names and types that match those of mapped properties, then it will instead call the parameterized constructor with values for those properties and will not set each property explicitly [types with constructors Ef core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/constructors)

I seems that your mapped property name is value and your constructor parameter name is zip code.